# Is there a way to make a <s:TabBar /> vertical?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way to make a `<s:TabBar />` vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it with a custom skinClass. I've changed the Datagroup's layout to VerticalLayout

Answer (score 1):

The source code here worked for me: http://hasseg.org/blog/post/112/vertical-tabnavigator-component-for-flex/

Comment: Sorry, this is for flex 3.5.. not sure if it will work for flex 4